# SQL adding columns together

Tags: sql, postgresql, addition, calculated-columns

I have a PostgreSQL table of 7k records. each record has 3 a unique ID and 3 fields with it. childcares, shcools, hospitals. there are all integer fields. i want to add a new column and calculate the total amount of receptors (schools,childcares,hospitals) for each row. I thought this should be pretty straighforward with adding a column and doing an insert with a select but i am not getting the results i want

```
alter table site add total integer;

insert into site(total) select sum(schools+childcares+hospitals) as s from site;
```

i have also tried a group by id in the insert select statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for `Update` not `Insert`

```
Update site 
 set total = COALESCE(schools,0)+COALESCE(childcares,0)+COALESCE(hospitals,0)
```

Added `COALESCE` to handle `NULL` values.

**Ex :**

`1 + 2 + NULL = NULL` so to replace `NULL` with `0` I have used `COALESCE`.

Now it will be `1 + 2 + 0(NULL) = 3`

Comment: what does coalesce do?

Comment: @ziggy - `Coalesce` will return the first `Not Null` value from the list. Am replacing the `NULL` value with `zero`.

Comment: @ziggy - You are trying insert new records into the table rather than updating the existing records